# Detect whether the first letters is consonant

Tags: r

Is there a way to detect whether the first letter of a word is consonant using the str_detect function?

For example: if I have the word 'house', I want the output to be 'TRUE'.

I have tried the following code but it's not working.

```
word<-c("house")
str_detect(word, "^(-[aeiou])")
```

Answer (score 4):

We can match all other characters other than aeiou with `^` inside the `[]`.  The `^` outside the `[` suggest the start of the string

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(word, "^[^aeiou]")
#[1] TRUE
```

Or another option is to negate (`!`)

```
!str_detect(word, "^[aeiou]")
```

---

Or can also use

```
substr(word, 1, 1) %in% setdiff(letters, c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or with `grepl` from `base R`

```
grepl('^[^aeiou]', word)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the string start marker `^`and the class of vowels? If the match returns FALSE you know it's a consonant:

```
str_detect(word, "^[aeiou]")
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun I created an own function `IsCons`

```
IsCons <- function(x)  {
  lower_consonant <- c("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
  upper_consonant <- toupper(consonant)
  a <- substring(x, 1, 1)
  a %in% lower_consonant | a %in% upper_consonant
}
```

check own function

```
word<-c("Ant", "House", "ant", "house")

IsCons(word)
```

Output

```
> IsCons(word)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Hurra it works!